# How to reduce the size of the tikz build images in a beamer presentation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I am preparing a beamer presentation and I need to insert in the slide some graphs build with the tikz method. However, they cover the full frame while I want this graphs to be smaller. How can I do this? Here's the code I am using :

```
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip=false,xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=3,axis lines=middle,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$\Dot{r}(t)$,ytick={0},xtick={2,4},yticklabels={$0$},xticklabels={$t_1$,$t_f$},xticklabel style={anchor= north}]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:2]{x};
\addplot[red,domain=2:4]{-x+4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the width like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
  \pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[clip=false,xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=3,axis lines=middle,xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$\Dot{r}(t)$,ytick={0},xtick={2,4},yticklabels={$0$},xticklabels={$t_1$,$t_f$},xticklabel style={anchor= north}]
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:2]{x};
  \addplot[red,domain=2:4]{-x+4};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  Some text over in the other column
  \end{column}
\end{columns}  
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Many thanks. What if I want to move the graph a tad to the right?

Comment: @dodo Try with a  `\hspace{1cm}` in front of it.